# Maximum Likelihood Classification fails every time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, likelihood

I'm trying to do image classification on a composit satellite image raster, it has 7 bands and every process I try fails.

I'm following a guide. In the training sample manager I have 6 classes (grassland, forest, cloud, water, urban, moorland) I could only create a signature file by saving it to desktop.

So next I open "Maximum Likelihood Classification" I picked my composit image raster as the "input raster bands", I put in the signature file in the "input signature file" box and kept everything else as default and every single time it fails and I don't know why because I'm literally following a guide.

So I'm wondering if anyone had any trouble with this, what did you do?

Comment: Do you get any error message or the software crashes? If you get any error message, please paste the message here as text.

Comment: It doesnt crash, I get an error.

'Maximum Likelihood Classification [135831_08042023]
Output classified raster: <empty> 
Output confidence raster: <empty>'

'ERROR 010328: Syntax error at or near symbol ,. 
ERROR 010267: Syntax error in parsing grid expression 
Failed to execute (MLClassify).'


I ran it twice away from my main project in a fresh workspace and I just get the same issue, ISO Cluster unsupervised works though when it didnt work previously.


I ran it away from my main project and ISO Cluster Unsupervised works.

Comment: Did you name your files correctly? Check whether you have any space in any of the files:  output/ input raster names/ the signature file name.